# Disadvantages of using reference parameter to return value in lock-free pop()

Tags: c++, multithreading, reference, smart-pointers, lock-free

I am currently reading Williams "C++ Concurrency in Action". Now I stopped on the topic dedicated to the implementation of lock-free pop().

Lock-free pop:

```
void pop(T& result)
{
 node* old_head = head.load();
 while(!head.compare_exchange_weak(old_head,old_head->next));
 result=old_head->data;
}
```

Here is a quote from the discussion of this code:

> The second problem is an **exception-safety issue**. When we first introduced the thread-safe stack back in chapter 3, you saw how just returning the object by value left you with an exception safety issue: if an exception is thrown when copying the return value, the value is lost. In that case, passing in a reference to the result was an acceptable solution because you could ensure that the stack was left unchanged if an exception was thrown. Unfortunately, here you don’t have that luxury; you can only safely **copy** the data once you know you’re the only thread returning the node, *which means the node has already been removed from the queue*. Consequently, **passing in the target for the return value by reference is no longer an advantage: you might as well just return by value**. If you want to return the value safely, you have to use the other option from chapter 3: return a (smart) pointer to the data value

I do not understand how the use of reference can lead to problems with exceptions. I see word 'copy' here, but it can't be used with references, 'initialization', 'assignment' but surely not 'copy'. So, I do not understand everyting that is written after this 'copy'.

While googling, I found a Williams explanation: https://forums.manning.com/posts/list/30887.page

but this does not clarify the question for me, because he uses 'copy' with references again:

"Normal" stack:

```
void pop(T& value)
{
 std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
 if(data.empty()) throw empty_stack();
 value=data.top();
 data.pop();
}
```

> With a "normal" stack, the **advantage of a reference** parameter for the result is that you can **copy the result before you remove** the node from the stack, and if the copy to the result throws then the node is still there for another call to take.

Here is my question: Does the use of references in this case could lead to the generation of exceptions, and why I may as well just return by value?

Comment: In the first quote, I think that he is referring to a different way of implementing `pop`: `T& pop()`. In that case, you are not copying the return value inside the function, as you do with `result = old_head->data;` but outside it (when you assign or copy construct using that reference).

Comment: `copy-assignment` is being done with `result = ...` in the first snippet, `value = ....` in the second. if that copy throws an exception, using an in/out reference in the lock-based code allows an algorithm of not losing the queue head (it isn't popped until after the copy). In the lockless code, the item must be removed from the queue *before* the copy. As such, the in/out reference is no longer an advantage (he never said it "lead to problems" as you seem to attribute). The reference doesn't introduce exceptions; the *copy* can (in either case).

Comment: Not related to the question here, but I think there could be a memory leak in the first code. Namely, who's freeing the old head node? Of course, I'm sure the book has the correct version or some context that would explain it though.

Comment: Yes, there is a memory leak, you're absolutely right, but it is an intermediate example from this book, unfinished.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `result=old_head->data;` you copy `old_head->data` in-to `result`. You are right that in this case assignment operator is used rather than copy constructor. But that's not important, important thing is that some non trivial actions may be needed to copy data from `old_head->data` to `result` and that actions may trigger an exception.

I think that Williams uses word "copy" because it is the most general world that can be used here. He also speaks about returning a value and in this case there may be invocation of copy constructor, move constructor, assignment operator and move assignment operator depending on the code. Instead of bloating text with a lot of verbs he just uses word "copy" because the only essential part is that we have data in one place and we need it in another.

Comment: Somebody really ought to re-write all of these articles about thread-safe queues etc. with respect to C++11; in particular, what becomes possible in the common case of noexcept move construction / move assignment.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm in something wrong all my life. I always thought that 'A reference is an alternative name for an object' ('value' becomes just a synonym for 'data.top()') , because this is a quote from B. Stroustroup, and there is no memory operation, allocation, deallocation and so on (except for const lvalue refs), so no single reason to throw. I am completely wrong?

Comment: @Razorfever: `T&` is mostly just syntactic sugar for `T*`, modulo rules about which constructor or `operator=` is invoked.  We're not changing the caller's reference variable to become a reference to the object just removed from the stack (and destroyed), we're copying the data from the lock-free stack into the caller's object (which we have a reference to).  I haven't read the whole question and comments thoroughly, so I'm not sure if this is what you're missing.

Comment: @Razorfever: `T& value` is a place where data must be stored. `old_head->data` is some other place where the data is. So we have to invoke `operator=` to copy it. If value is POD things are really simple and no exceptions will be thrown. But you can write custom `operator=` and you are allowed to throw an exception from it. For example `std::string::operator=` may throw `bad_alloc` because data is stored in a buffer located in dynamic memory. And Williams in his book describes how to make robust container which will behave good even if value throws exceptions during copy.

Comment: My mistake was quite trivial: i did not understand that by the time of calling pop(T&) the T& must exist, and be initialized with something (point to somewhere, internally), and 'value=data.top()' just overwriting this 'something' by calling operator=, as @Peter Cordes and others noted. Of course, executing 'operator=' can lead to exceptions of different kinds. Thanks everyone.